# Javascript function argument and variable

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write a function like this in JS?

```
function functionName(element) {
   var element = something
}
```

i mean both the function argument and a variable inside the same function is defined by the same name. is this valid js?

Comment: Did you try it? It's possible, but makes no sense really

Comment: Should take three seconds to test -> http://jsfiddle.net/wpuxw3xx/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Because like @adeneo said, it makes no sense...

Comment: The `var` is ignored; there can only be one binding to a given symbol in a particular lexical context.

Comment: it didn't show ny error on console. it's just i ran out of variable names...

Comment: *I ran out of variable names* - what?

Comment: check this please... this is what i was trying to acheive... http://jsfiddle.net/s467wq90/

Comment: @Pointy - seriously, that happens all the time, whenever `foo`, `element` and `event` is taken, what else is there ?

Comment: @adeneo i wanted to make my code as easy as possible for my customers is all

Comment: @nameless Well, why don't you call your argument `elementId` since that's what it is? The only time you may redefine an argument that was passed in is when you want to specify a default value, but then again the `var` keyword is superfluous.

Comment: @plalx yup that's good. thank u. that's what i'm gonna do...

Comment: thank ya all for ur comments and answers...

Answer (score 1):

As @adeneo said: It's possible, but makes no sense really.

You probably mean to use like this:

```
function functionName(element) {
   var something = element
}
```